# Use taxonomy_get_tree() to extract term names?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using the handy `taxonomy_get_tree()` function to, hopefully, just extract the list of term names within a vocabulary. Sounds simple enough, but I'm stumped. Running the following:

```
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree(2);
print_r($tree);
```

yields the following:

```
      Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 1
            [vid] => 2
            [name] => The First Term
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 0
            [guid] => 
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tid] => 2
            [vid] => 2
            [name] => The Second Term
            [description] => 
            [weight] => 1
            [guid] => 
            [depth] => 0
            [parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Now all I want to do is pull out each of the `name` values. So I tried the following:

```
foreach($tree as $value){
    print($value['name']);
}
```

I'm returning a server error. I suspect it has something to do with that pesky `stdClass Object` thing.

So any ideas how I can extract just the `name`s?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491143/how-to-get-objectstdclass-from-array) works:

```
foreach($tree as $value){
    print($value->name);
}
```

Thankfully, it looks like I'm not the only idiot out there. Sigh...

Comment: I know exactly how you feel.